# Samsung stock browser timeout when fetching external resources

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I had an web app that fetches all static assets from AWS; however, all the fetch requests for external resources time out on Samsung browser (version 5.4). 
In addition, it cannot grab the external script files such as 

  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>`

But the app works Chrome, Firefox...etc on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with VPN setting on Android stock browser. Android stock browser blocks third party asset when VPN is on for reason. Works perfectly without VPN on.